# Reading strings from *.txt file on PC through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I just want to read integers from "my_file.txt" which is stored on my PC. "paramString" I pass through is the string "my_file.txt".But myReader.readLine ruturns NULL. However, myReader has certain value.Actually, I am not so familiar with the use of FileInputStream or DataInputStream... I just want to read some string or integers from .txt files stored on my PC.Thank you.

`FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(paramString);`

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
 BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    int i = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());`
```

Also,an exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at bpn.BackpropagationNet.readConversionFile(BackpropagationNet.java:232)
    at bpn.BPN.main(BPN.java:72)"

has been reported by eclipse.

Thanks again.

Comment: Using your code, with paramString as "test.txt", relating to a file in the source directory containing the String "test text" produced the expected result for me (i.e. NumberFormatException for string "test text"). Are you 100% sure the file is in the right place?

Comment: You can test if the file exists by adding `System.out.println(new File(paramString).exists());` as the first line of the block.

Comment: FileInputStream doesn't read text, it reads bytes(like an image file, etc).  Use FileReader to read a .txt file.

Comment: @Thomas Seems to read text fine using the specified code.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to read the data using:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(paramString));
int i = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
```

It's not necessary to use `DataInputStreamReader` for this, nor converting from `Stream` to `Reader`, you can create reader directly.

Comment: Thank you very much,everyone. Actually,both of my original code and code provided by @krzyk could work... The key problem which leads to my reading falsely is: I want to create a special *.cnv file in my directory and read strings from it.However, after I use "New a Text Document",the file name becomes "*.cnv.txt"... I still want to read it as "*.cnv"... That is the critical point... Now my code run successfully. Thanks again,everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a NumberFormatException its probly because of the

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(myReader.readLine());
```

line. If you just `System.out.println(myReader.readLine());` does it display the line of the file correctly?

Comment: It also might be way easier to just use a scanner then call the .nextInt() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Actually, I add a trace like this: System.out.println( "before parseInt:"+myReader.readLine()+"\n" );The result is "before parseInt:null".Is it helpful?

Comment: Are you set on using the Reader
you can just do `File file = new File("ur input file");`
then `Scanner in = new Scanner(file);`
`int i = in.nextInt();`

Comment: @XiaoliangWang You can also verity that current line has  valid number string by using regex of  `"\\d+"`